# Git crashes when: git config --list

Tags: git, git-bash

I am squeaky new on Git but am familiar with the basics. Unfortunately, every time I give the `git config --list` command, it starts listing off the usual but then says `(END)`. I am unable to do anything but close and reopen Git Bash when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is merely that you don't know how to use your Terminal (or wherever the command line is being used). You're set to use a PAGER and when it comes to the end it prints END. It might be `less`, for example. If so, type `q` to exit.